# How to display multiple byte array images in the HTML

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, arrays

I have a List of byte array images.

I am showing an image in HTML page.
If I want to display 25 such images I have to go 25 times to the database.

I want to avoid that please help.

#### HTML code

```
myProfile.init(function (map) {
    dom.byId("Image").src="UserImageDisplay?&userId="+map["userId"];    
}
```

#### Java code

```
byte[] image = userSession.getPhoto(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));

response.setContentType("image/imagetype");

OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

out.write(image);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well You have get the Image from somewhere , be it a DB or a File Server.

Since you have suggested , you dont want to load it every time from DB.

Here's what i would do to improve the performance.

1) `Cache your images` whenever you fetch one(thats not available in Cache) from the Db.
2)`The cache can be Server Memory`(highly advice against this , as you can quickly run out of memory) , `or cache the images in local storage`.

3) `Storing of images in the cache` , can be `done realtime` ie when the file is requested from the Web App, or `you could schedule a cron/batch job` to do that before hand .Preferably during off peak hours.

Choice between`3 and 4 depends on how frequent the images are updated in the Database`. I will leave it up to you.

4) You can explicitly `specify the browser to cache the images`.You can accomplish it with 
 [tag](http://www.metatags.info/meta_http_equiv_cache_control)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should cache your images.

Best would be you start a cron job that generates image files.